# Multiple firewalls (Admin and user)

Tags: symfony

My application need 2 firewalls, one for Admin and the other for User. In my security.yml I config:

```
    admin:
        pattern:      ^/admin
        provider:     fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            login_path:     /admin/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:     /admin/logout
            target: /admin
        anonymous: ~

    # defaut login area for standard users
    main:
        pattern:      ^/
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path:     /logout
        anonymous:    ~
```

I don't know whether this config is correct. Everything's OK when I login from **main** area, but when I login from **admin**, it's redirect me to the home path instead of  **default_target_path**. I try to change provider to a custom provider (eg in_memory) to re-check the **admin** firewall, but I still login by user from fos_userbundle provider. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed main firewall pattern to  ^/(?!admin), everything's ok now. Thanks for your help!

```
    main:
        pattern:      ^/(?!admin)
        provider:       default_provider
        anonymous:    ~

    admin:
        pattern:      ^/admin
        provider:     admin_provider
        anonymous:    ~
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it's because there is a main pattern 
main:
        pattern:      ^/
it control even the ^/admin
try to replace ^/ with ^/home or ^/main it will work on bothe

Answer (score 0):

Try removing anonymous and using access control instead. In theory Symfony2 will automatically redirect users from admin back, even if they are using the same login screen.

The security in Symfony2 is cascading (so /admin will also appear under main)

e.g. 
    # defaut login area for standard users
    main:
        pattern:      ^/
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path:     /logout

```
admin:
    pattern:      ^/admin
    provider:     fos_userbundle
    form_login:
        use_forward:    false
        failure_path:   null
        target: /admin/dashboard
        always_use_default_target_path: true
    logout:
        target: /admin

 access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER] }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

you'll likely need different ROLES specified.

Comment: Thank you. I try changing my config as your guide, but when I go to page /admin it redirect me to /login page in main firewall. I need 2 login page for 2 firewalls which have 2 separate providers.

Comment: your security.yml lists the same provider (fos_userbundle).

Comment: try, just 'target: /admin/dashboard'